# can not access global 'allure' object using mocha-allure

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, allure

According to mocha-allure docs, if you want to use allure outside of  before/beforeEach you should import the reporter directly. Or once added mocha-allure-reporter will create global allure object with the following API:

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-mocha

https://github.com/allure-examples/mocha-allure-example/blob/master/test/simple.spec.js

However I followed the example in the docs, but i get `Cannot find name 'allure'.` , when using it in either the before or afterEach.

test file:

```
require('mocha-allure-reporter');
// const allure = require('mocha-allure-reporter'); // also tried this

describe( 'test', () => {
// code



before(async () => {
  // code here
});


  afterEach('first step', function () {
        const testStep = allure.createStep('initial', () => {
            console.log('create step');
          });
    });
```

config:

```
mochaOpts: {
        reporterOptions: {
            reporterEnabled:
                mocha-allure-reporter,
          mochaAllureReporterReporterOptions: {
                targetDir: './reports/allure-results',
            },
```

Comment: are you able to find `mocha-allure-reporter` in your `node_modules`. If not use `npm i mocha-allure-reporter` from your project folder.

Comment: yes `mocha-allure-reporter` is already in `node_modules`

Comment: you are getting error from `config` or from the `test` file. because you are using `mocha-allure-reporter` in both places

Comment: from the test file

Comment: if importing in your `config` do not throw any error, Import similar way in your spec

Comment: but in the config, its just added to mochaOpts. So how to use it in the spec then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one

```
const allure = require('mocha-allure-reporter');
```

allure is a global identifier, injected by reporter to your code.

Add the following line to the top of your file to tell Typescript about it

```
declare const allure: any;
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: The initial error is gone. But allure.createStep still does not work. 

Posted new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125425/createattachment-using-mocha-allure-reporter

Comment: @Madhan what file should this be in??

Answer (score 0):

Quick additional bit: createStep is a self invoking function. You're not calling it.

So in summary:

1: For Typescript we need the quick and dirty declaration for Allure "global" functionality. The reporter will inject it, but this is needed to make it 'accessible'. Note: This will not provide typing support (little help still needed to find that btw).

```
declare const allure: any;
```

2: createStep requires a self-invoking call, so instead use:

```
allure.createStep('initial', () => {
    console.log('create step');
})();
```

If you are using this asynchronously, remember to use the await call

```
allure.createStep('initial', () => {
    console.log('create step');
})();
```