# Protractor / Typescript - Cannot find name 'allure' in "mocha-allure-reporter"

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, protractor, mocha.js, allure

Basically i have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105020/can-not-access-global-allure-object-using-mocha-allure) question but in mocha-allure-reporter and ***typescript***. I'm using protractor with mocha and decided to add allure reporting

'allure' object using mocha-allure cannot be accessed globally.

Here's the protractor.conf.js

```
mochaOpts: {
    bail: false,
    ui: 'bdd',
    reporter: 'spec',
    compiler: 'ts:ts-node/register'
}
```

Here's the ***devDependencies*** in  package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.0.0",
    "mocha-allure-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "mocha-tags": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

And the ***dependencies***

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.6",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha-allure-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "graphviz": "0.0.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "npm-failsafe": "^0.4.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.2",
    "typescript-logging": "^0.6.4",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7",
    "yargs": "^13.3.0"
}
```

Here's the ts file that cannot access 'allure' globally:

[image]

And when I try to add `declare const allure: any;`,
[image]
*Note: In typescript please, I don't have much background in javascript*

Comment: Have you tried `const allure = require("mocha-allure-reporter")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 require("mocha-allure-reporter");
 declare const allure: any;

 describe("Initial Test", function() {
 it("Add Feature" async function() {
    allure.feature("Sample Feature");
  })
 })
```

Comment: I already did. It throws an error `TypeError: allure.feature is not a function`.

Comment: @miel-yan well, I have updated the answer. If it doesn't work. We discuss this over any screen sharing platform

Comment: I have already tried that too. Sure! I would love to do that.